# lxml xml parsing users

Tags: python, xml, parsing, lxml

i just want to parse users from my xml file with python lxml;

here is my xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<users>
    <user id="1">
        <username>xxx</username>
        <password>xxx</password>
        <email>xxx@example.com</email>
        <nickname>xxx</nickname>
        <phone>xxx</phone>
        <status>xxx</status>
    </user>
</users>
```

i searched a lot but i couldn't find a real good example about it. Thanks for your helps...

Comment: Try searching harder. lxml provides very good tutorials, go there. http://lxml.de/tutorial.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this will give you a head start:

```
>>> s = b"""\
... <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
... <users>
...     <user id="1">
...         <username>xxx</username>
...         <password>xxx</password>
...         <email>xxx@example.com</email>
...         <nickname>xxx</nickname>
...         <phone>xxx</phone>
...         <status>xxx</status>
...     </user>
... </users>
... """
>>> t = etree.XML(s)
>>> t.xpath('//username/text()')
['xxx']
>>> t.find('user[@id="1"]/username').text
'xxx'
>>> t.find('user[@id="1"]/password').text
'xxx'
…
```

Comment: for example i want to select user by id and print username or other elements, how can i do that? aaand how can i modify or delete the whole block, sorry for my silly questions but i can't figure out how can i do that :')